# How to retrieve and update the data in a nested xml file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am working on this xml file stored in my AWS s3 bucket, I have to update the value tags in the ATTRIBUTES tag. Can any body help me that how can I travel to the value tags and update the values in them? I am using minidom module and this is fetched as a class-xml.dom.minidom.Document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PPL DATE="11/03/2021 14:58:58" USER="XXXX" WORKSTATION="FFFFF">
<PPLScene>
<ATTRIBUTES>
<VALUE NAME="SoilDescription" TYPE="String">Compacted Earth</VALUE>
<VALUE NAME="Latitude" TYPE="Double">38.25858101</VALUE>
<VALUE NAME="Longitude" TYPE="Double">-122.04101444</VALUE>
<VALUE NAME="ElevationMetersAboveMSL" TYPE="Double">-28.8674275705822</VALUE>
<VALUE NAME="DescriptionOverride" TYPE="String" />
<VALUE NAME="Guid" TYPE="String">ab0b7bdf-ad4f-4548-be4e-f457e61e1b53</VALUE>
<VALUE NAME="TreeNodeExpanded" TYPE="Boolean">True</VALUE>
<VALUE NAME="SelectedLoadCase" TYPE="Int32">0</VALUE>
<VALUE NAME="PPLVersion" TYPE="Int32">602</VALUE>
<VALUE NAME="WorkingDataStore" TYPE="String" />
</ATTRIBUTES>
</PPLScene>
</PPL>
```

I am using the following python code but no luck...

```
import boto3
import requests
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML, fromstring, parse
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

bucket = 'bucketname'
pplx_file_int = 'Pole.xml'
key = pplx_file_int
print(str(key))
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = key)
file_data = obj['Body'].read()
print(file_data)
xmldoc = minidom.parseString(file_data)
print(type(xmldoc))
print(xmldoc.nodeName)
print(xmldoc.firstChild.tagName)
procedureList = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('PPLChildElements')
for procElement in procedureList:
ListOfData2 = procElement.getElementsByTagName('WoodPole')
for attributes in ListOfData2:
element_1 = procElement.getElementsByTagName('ATTRIBUTES')
print(element_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend using parsel:

```sh
pip install parsel
```

Makes css and xpath convenient to use mate!

```py
from parsel import Selector
sel = Selector(text=u"""
        <PPL DATE="11/03/2021 14:58:58" USER="XXXX" WORKSTATION="FFFFF">
<PPLScene>
<ATTRIBUTES>
<VALUE NAME="SoilDescription" TYPE="String">Compacted Earth</VALUE>
<VALUE NAME="Latitude" TYPE="Double">38.25858101</VALUE>
<VALUE NAME="Longitude" TYPE="Double">-122.04101444</VALUE>
<VALUE NAME="ElevationMetersAboveMSL" TYPE="Double">-28.8674275705822</VALUE>
<VALUE NAME="DescriptionOverride" TYPE="String" />
<VALUE NAME="Guid" TYPE="String">ab0b7bdf-ad4f-4548-be4e-f457e61e1b53</VALUE>
<VALUE NAME="TreeNodeExpanded" TYPE="Boolean">True</VALUE>
<VALUE NAME="SelectedLoadCase" TYPE="Int32">0</VALUE>
<VALUE NAME="PPLVersion" TYPE="Int32">602</VALUE>
<VALUE NAME="WorkingDataStore" TYPE="String" />
</ATTRIBUTES>
</PPLScene>
</PPL>""")

print("===============Text Fields==================")
for name_attr in sel.css('PPL PPLScene ATTRIBUTES VALUE'):
  print(name_attr.css("::text").get()) # Text


print("===============Atttributes==================")
for name_attr in sel.css('PPL PPLScene ATTRIBUTES > VALUE'):
  if ('name' in name_attr.attrib ):
    print(name_attr.attrib['name']) # Text
```